# This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V error

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I'm using Android Studio on windows 10 currently. However, as I try to install HAXM via android studio, there is an error which always pops up "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed".

[image: The error message]

The weird thing is that when I checked my installed programs, HAXM is already installed by default. I have no idea why I am not able to upgrade. I'm using a decent gaming laptop with an 8th Gen Intel Core i7 processor.

Things I have tried :

I have already went into my bios and made sure all virtualization options were enabled and went to "Windows Features"and unchecked Windows Hyper-visor Platform but to no avail as the problem still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same issue, and even though Intel virtualization was enabled in the BIOS and my Windows 10 doesn't have the Hyper-V option because it's the home edition, I wasn't able to use Android Studio emulators/virtual machines or upgrade/reinstall Intel HAXM. I then found out that an enabled feature on Windows Defender was the cause of the problem. Try the following steps (sorry, my device is in portuguese so the options might have another naming other than the direct translation to english):

1. In Windows Defender, go to Device Security (The one with a laptop icon).
   [image]
2. Choose Kernel Isolation Details (first option).
   [image]
3. And disable the Memory Integrity option if it isn't disabled already (in case it is, I'm sorry but this solution won't help you out).
4. If you have to change the option to disabled, restart your computer and try upgrading HAXM via Android Studio again.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I just did this and it worked (Intel HAXM installed), but then I re-enabled it and the emulator wouldn't start up. After some googling, some say that this setting forces Hyper-V on, and Micorosft's [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-exploit-guard/memory-integrity) says sth along those lines as well. So for now, unfortunately it seems like you have to sacrifice security while running your Android emulator. Worst part is, it requires a restart to enable/disable this option :/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after disabling Hyper-V in Windows Features I had to turn the antivirus (Kaspersky) off to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) 7.5.6 on Windows 10 Pro (1909).

Answer (score 0):

IF u have AMD CPU you have to install Driver for AMD processor [Check img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Iry.png)

Comment: The OP said in the question that they have an Intel processor, not an AMD processor.

Comment: This helped me. I was unaware that AMD computers required additional configurations.